# Can you choose which way you move when casting Mirror Image?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

When casting Mirror Image, you slide in one direction while the other Mirror Images created go in other directions, to misdirect the enemy. Sometimes, the sliding puts me in an advantageous position, and other times it moves me exactly where I didn't want to be.

Is there any way to control which way I go when casting Mirror Image?

Comment: from my experience, no but I haven't really tried to manipulate them that way

Comment: I haven't used it in a while but if I remember correctly it either pushed me in the direction I was facing, or I think less likely, the direction where my cursor.

Answer (score 3):

No.

The direction you go after casting is based on where you end up in the triangle (or pentagon) and that is completely random.